# Wxwidget window crashes when opened via firefox p11 module

Tags: c++, linux, firefox, shared-libraries, wxwidgets

I have a function in my pkcs#11 library that I want to open a wxwidgets window when called. The function will be called when the pkcs#11 C_Sign function is called by firefox. (My C_Sign function calls login_dialog)

Here is the code

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include "wx/wxprec.h"
#include <pthread.h>

class wxP11App2 : public wxApp
{
public:
  virtual bool OnInit();
};

DECLARE_APP(wxP11App2)
// Use _NO_MAIN since we don't want main() to be created
IMPLEMENT_APP_NO_MAIN(wxP11App2);


bool wxP11App2::OnInit()
{
  printf("OnInit\n");
  wxFrame *frame = new wxFrame((wxFrame*) NULL, -1, _T("Hello wxWidgets World"));
  frame->CreateStatusBar();
  frame->SetStatusText(_T("Hello World"));
  frame->Show(true);
  SetTopWindow(frame);
  printf("OnInit done\n");
  return true;
}


void* start_wxapp_func(void* args)
{
  printf("Thread func\n");

  int argc = 0;
  wxChar* argv = NULL;

  wxApp* pApp = new wxP11App2();
  wxApp::SetInstance(pApp);
  wxEntry(argc, &argv);

  return NULL;
}

int login_dialog()
{
  int rv = 0;

  pthread_t thread1;
  pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, start_wxapp_func, NULL);

  int count = 0;
  while(1) {
    printf("Sleep: %d\n", count++);
    sleep(1);
  }

  return rv;
}
```

However, firefox crashes when wxEntry is being called. If I call C_Sign from a newly created c++ program (as opposed to when firefox calls the C_Sign function) it works. I get my wxwidgets window. I don't use any other GUI in that program. (There is neither any wxwidgets context nor gtk context).

It seems that it's gtk that crashes firefox so I thought it might have something to do that firefox already has a gtk instance running (and since wxwidgets uses gtk it might be a problem).

Do you have any suggestions on what I should try?

UPDATE:

Here is a stack trace from firefox built with debug info:

```
0   gdk_drawable_get_screen mozgtk.c    561 0x7f5ab2291b09  
1   wx_gdk_window_get_screen    gtk2-compat.h   391 0x7f5a859beca4  
2   wxClientDisplayRect display.cpp 80  0x7f5a859bedb2  
3   wxGetClientDisplayRect  gdicmn.cpp  902 0x7f5a85ae5300  
4   wxTopLevelWindowBase::GetDefaultSize    toplvcmn.cpp    216 0x7f5a85b7f8fb  
5   wxTopLevelWindowGTK::Create toplevel.cpp    571 0x7f5a859d3955  
6   wxFrame::Create frame.cpp   56  0x7f5a85a3bb75  
7   wxFrame::wxFrame    frame.h 31  0x7f5a8679dd0c  
8   wxP11App2::OnInit   LoginDlg_linux.cpp  27  0x7f5a8679d825  
9   wxAppConsoleBase::CallOnInit    app.h   93  0x7f5a8679db95  
10  wxEntry init.cpp    479 0x7f5a858b789f  
11  start_wxapp_func    LoginDlg_linux.cpp  47  0x7f5a8679da2a  
12  start_thread        312 0x7f5ab1e60182  
13  clone       111 0x7f5ab116947d
```

So in my code, it's the creation of a new wxFrame that crashes the program.

Comment: Where does it crash? Have you looked at the stack trace? It might contain something useful, even if the problem is indeed likely to be using incompatible GTK+ or dependent libraries versions.

Comment: It crashes in OnInit, when creating the new frame. I have updated the question with a stack trace

Comment: Yes, it seems like it has to do with firefox already using gtk. I try to do configure with the --with-x11 switch and --disable-shared and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is really due to using 2 sets of mismatching GTK+ libraries, then the most straightforward solution is to build wxWidgets using exactly the same version of GTK+ and dependent libraries that was used for building your Firefox. In practice, the simplest way to do it would probably be to build it under the same system where Firefox was built.

This is definitely not ideal from the maintenance perspective, but unfortunately I just can't suggest any other solution. If your code is GPL you could try linking GTK+ statically, but it's usually not recommended for various reasons and if it's not GPL you can't do it anyhow.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This problem has been put on hold for now for me. I will try your suggestion when I will work with it again.